# Composition is not creating foreign key reference

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have two domains classes as follows,

```
class Agent {
    String name
    Team team
}

class Team {
    String name 
    Agent primarySupervisor
    static hasMany = [secondarySupervisors:Agent]
}
```

Every agent has a team, every team has a primary supervisor and multiple secondary supervisors.

Above code doesn't create a table for secondary supervisors mapping and if I remove team property from **Agent** domain or primarySupervisor from **Team** domain then it creates mapping table.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This domain class structure should work for you.

```
 class Agent {
        String name
        static belongsTo = Team
        static hasOne = [team: Team] // Every agent has a team
    }

    class Team {
        String name 
        static hasMany = [secondarySupervisors:Agent] // every team has a primary supervisor and multiple secondary supervisors
    }
```

Here has many relationship will form a new table as **team_agent**.